# Scrollable grid-like view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm writing an app with a view that has a grid of images (3x3) and it needs to have infinite scroll per row and per column with snap to position, very similar to the 'Design Museum Collection' app.  How would I go about implementing this view? Is there a library that already supports this? I would like to implement this natively in IOS.  Can I use UIScrollView or do I need to create this bidirectional scroll view from scratch.  Here is a video of the 'Design Museum Collection' app (http://vimeo.com/39260302).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It's been quite a while since your question but as I've been struggling with the same thing I'm gonna answer it for future reference...

Sadly I could not find a good solution anywhere so after a lot of hours of experimenting I came up with this: https://github.com/AlvinNutbeij/DWGridController

It's still a work in progress but very usable for your purpose I'd say!

Answer (score 2):

See the tutorial [*How To Make An Interface With Horizontal Tables Like The Pulse News App*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1). It will guide you through the basics.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this out: [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).